Unofficial NVIDIA Fermi drivers for newer Linux kernels?
As the official NVIDIA 391.xx drivers don't support Linux 6.x, I'm forced to use noveau, but the performance is very bad.
Is there an unofficial version of these drivers for newer Linux kernels?
Thanks in advance for your reply.

Solved.
Solution:

Downgrade to kernel 6.8
Add this PPA:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/build

and update:
sudo apt update


Remove any previously installed drivers:
sudo apt purge nvidia* && sudo apt autoremove


Install the driver:
sudo apt install nvidia-legacy-390xx-driver


Set environmental variable GSK_RENDERER to cairo:
sudo printf "\nGSK_RENDERER=cairo\n">>/etc/environment


Reboot and enjoy!

Working on Linux Mint 22 with GT 730 4 GB (Fermi).

RPMFusion (a third-party Fedora repository) has all the necessary patches:
https://github.com/rpmfusion/nvidia-390xx-kmod
I presume some other distros may have them as well, probably you need to use the distro that actually does the job of maintaining older NVIDIA drivers.
You've not specified yours, so it's hard to say.
Also, we've had twelve 6.x kernel releases already and you've not bothered to specify that either.

Thanks for the answer. I was looking for one preferably for Ubuntu and it's derivatives (like Linux mint), but I can change the distro if needed. The kernel version doesn't matter that much, it can be for any 6.x version. I'm currently using kernel 6.12.3 on Linux mint, but again, I can downgrade if required.

There's no need to distrohop. 6.12 is brand new, perhaps it's not even in Mint yet officially. AFAIK they follow and use Ubuntu's kernels and for them their NVIDIA repos must be enough. And if you insist on using unsupported kernels, well you ave to take care of the rest. Maybe you could even learn C and become a maintainer yourself.

It might not be officially supported, but I installed the kernel using Mainline kernels. I might already have found the solution though. What do you think of https://daanberg.net/en/kennisbank/using-older-nvidia-drivers-on-linux/ ?

PPAs are OK to use if 1) You download the source package and check it's OK 2) You update manually. Anyone can upload anything to their PPA, including malware. Ubuntu doesn't have the people or money to verify all the PPAs are safe to use.
